# Is it better to use a "partial" for loop for this code or a while loop?

Tags: java, loops

I just came across the following code:

```
for(Iterator<String> iterator = stuff.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
   ...
}
```

This strikes me as a sort of misuse of a `for`... Wouldn't this code be better as:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = stuff.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   ...
}
```

?

Any specific reasons anyone can think of to use the `for`? Which is the better approach?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no real difference, other than personal preference. I suppose some people might prefer the "for..." variation because it uses 1 less line of code, but I find it harder to read.

Comment: What's the "misuse" of the for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `stuff`? Can you apply [enhanced for loop](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/32-new-features-in-java-50-1.html) for it?

```
for (String str : stuff) {
   doSmth (str);
}
```

The only reason to use iterators explicitly is to remove certain elements while looping with `iterator.remove()`.

Comment: I may be able to use a foreach in this situation... but what if it's not a native Java collection and is user-defined, so for-each can't be used but it has its own iterator?

Comment: just implement Iterable<T> for enable the use of for-each for your own objects

Comment: If it's an old (i.e. written with java 1.4 or earlier) 3rd-party library then I'd prefer while loop. It's more clean and makes code more readable.

Answer (score 7):

I'd prefer

```
for (String string : stuff) {
    ...
}
```

Much cleaner, and there is rarely an actual use for the `Iterator`.

The enhanced for loop can be applied to anything which implements [`Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which only requires the `iterator()` method.

If that is not possible, I prefer the first version because it limits the scope of the iterator without requiring an extra set of brackets (you could wrap the `while` version inside `{}` to get the same effect, but with an additional level of indentation).

Answer (score 4):

The for loop is better because the scope of the Iterator is limited to inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a *foreach* loop? from 1.5..

```
for (Element el : collection) {
  // do whatever
}
```